# How to apply list comprehension on multiple columns in a dataframe?

Tags: string, list, dataframe, comparison

I'm setting up a new column of 0s and 1s in my dataframe based on the values of other columns in that row. The value should equal 1 if any of the following conditions are true, and 0 otherwise:

```
y_train['SEPSISPATOS']=='Yes' OR
y_train['SEPSHOCKPATOS'] == 'Yes' OR 
y_train['OTHSYSEP'] == 'Sepsis' OR
y_train['OTHSESHOCK'] == 'Septic Shock'
```

I've tried using list comprehensions and np.select (code below)

```
NSQIPdf_train = pd.read_csv("acs_nsqip_puf13_2.csv",sep=',',encoding='utf-8')
y_train = NSQIPdf_train.loc[:,('SEPSISPATOS','SEPSHOCKPATOS', 'OTHSYSEP', 'OTHSESHOCK')]

### trying list comprehension
y_train['SEPSIS_STATUS'] = [1 if (x['SEPSISPATOS'] == 'Yes') or (x['SEPSHOCKPATOS'] == 'Yes') or (x['OTHSYSEP'] == 'Sepsis') or (x['OTHSESHOCK'] == 'Septic Shock') else 0 for x in y_train]

### trying np.select
y_train['SEPSIS_STATUS'] = [1 if (x['SEPSISPATOS'] == 'Yes') or (x['SEPSHOCKPATOS'] == 'Yes') or (x['OTHSYSEP'] == 'Sepsis') or (x['OTHSESHOCK'] == 'Septic Shock') else 0 for x in y_train]
conditions=[
    (y_train['SEPSISPATOS'] == 'Yes'),
    (y_train['SEPSHOCKPATOS'] == 'Yes'),
    (y_train['OTHSYSEP'] == 'Sepsis'),
    (y_train['OTHSESHOCK'] == 'Septic Shock')]
choices=[1,1,1,1]
y_train['SEPSIS_STATUS'] = np.select(conditions,choices,default=0)

print (y_train)
print (y_train.dtypes)
```

Using np.select, you can see where OTHSESHOCK='Septic Shock' in row 3, SEPSIS_STATUS is still 0, where I am instead expecting 1. The string comparison does not seem to work (sample output below - I am wondering if this is because dtype of the columns is 'object' because of how Pandas reads in csv files instead of string)

```
       SEPSISPATOS SEPSHOCKPATOS  ...          OTHSESHOCK SEPSIS_STATUS
0            b'No'         b'No'  ...  b'No Complication'             0
1            b'No'         b'No'  ...  b'No Complication'             0
2            b'No'         b'No'  ...  b'No Complication'             0
3            b'No'         b'No'  ...     b'Septic Shock'             0
4            b'No'         b'No'  ...  b'No Complication'             0
5            b'No'         b'No'  ...  b'No Complication'             0
6            b'No'         b'No'  ...  b'No Complication'             0
7            b'No'         b'No'  ...  b'No Complication'             0
8            b'No'         b'No'  ...  b'No Complication'             0
```

When using list comprehension, I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'str'.
```

Finally, here are the dtypes of my variables when using print(df.dtypes)

```
SEPSISPATOS      object
SEPSHOCKPATOS    object
OTHSYSEP         object
OTHSESHOCK       object
SEPSIS_STATUS     int32
dtype: object
```

Help much appreciated. I've tried multiple ways, but am open to other suggestions or fixes. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try casting your columns to be strings. Not sure what the name of your dataframe is, but something like the below should work.

```
df.SEPSIS_SHOCK = df.SEPSIS_SHOCK.astype(str)
```

Comment: I'd also tried that without success using y_train=y_train.astype(str). Printing dtypes still yields 'object', and comparison does not seem to work.